# I am trying to parse JSON feed and display it into a Custom Listview but I am getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-volley

I am trying to parse JSON feed and display it into a Custom Listview but I am getting NullPointerException. Here's the code I am using, I have used volley and parsed the response , which is working properly on a simple listview but having issues with custom listview . Please anyone resolve this it would be grateful.

```
public class News extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    String uri = "http://lodhisamaj.16mb.com/jsongen.php";
    String[] newstitle;
    String[] newsdesc;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.news);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newslist);
    Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this, newstitle, newsdesc);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, uri, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray title = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
                            String xy = title.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                    "Title");
                            String xy2 = title.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                    "Meassage");
                            xy = newstitle[i];
                            xy2 = newsdesc[i];
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    rq.add(jreq);
}}             


class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descArray;

public Myadapter(Context c, String[] newstitle, String[] newsdesc) {
    super(c, R.layout.news_row, newstitle);
    this.context = c;
    this.titleArray = newstitle;
    this.descArray = newsdesc;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.news_row, parent, false);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newstitle);
    TextView mydec = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsdec);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    mydec.setText(descArray[position]);
    return row;
}}
```

Comment: What line causes the NPE?

Comment: 1. - why do you hate formatting. and 2. - add logcat.

Comment: it is happening because i am populating the list view before data is arrived

Comment: `Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this, newstitle, newsdesc);` <-- `newstitle` and `newsdesc` are null here.

Comment: @cricket_007 so how can I make those reference to point to my string[] variable made while in json parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else works, you can correct the NullPointerException (and the IndexOutOfBoundsException), by switching the `String[]` to `ArrayList<String>`.

The problem is these two lines do not initialize the `String[]`, so they will be null.

```
String[] newstitle;
String[] newsdesc;
```

---

Additionally, not sure what these 2 lines were intending to do...

```
xy = newstitle[i];
xy2 = newsdesc[i];
```

---

That being said, hopefully this will work for you. (Untested)

```
public class News extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    String uri = "http://lodhisamaj.16mb.com/jsongen.php";
    ArrayList<String> newstitle;
    ArrayList<String> newsdesc;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.news);

    // Initialize your lists so they are not null
    newstitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    newsdesc = new ArrayList<String>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newslist);
    Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this, newstitle, newsdesc);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, uri, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray title = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
                            String xy = title.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                    "Title");
                            String xy2 = title.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                    "Meassage");

                            // Add your strings to your lists
                            newstitle.add(xy);
                            newsdesc.add(xy2);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace(); // never ignore your errors
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    rq.add(jreq);
}}             


class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> titleArray;
    ArrayList<String> descArray;

public Myadapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> newstitle, ArrayList<String> newsdesc) {
    super(c, R.layout.news_row, newstitle);
    this.context = c;
    this.titleArray = newstitle;
    this.descArray = newsdesc;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.news_row, parent, false);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newstitle);
    TextView mydec = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsdec);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray.get(position));
    mydec.setText(descArray.get(position));
    return row;
}}
```

Comment: Very Very thank you for resolving my silly mistake! it Worked .  God Bless :)